# How to fix ReturnUrl from breaking pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a return url for users if they are not logged in placed inside of the middleware:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    string UserSessionId = context.Session.GetString("_Uid");
    // If the session is not set the user needs to login
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserSessionId))
    {
        // If the current path equals / it's likely the first visit on the site
        // Do not redirect this request
        if (context.Request.Path.Value.Equals("/"))
        {
            await next();
            return;
        }
        // If the path is anything other than /Login require the user to login and return them to the previous URL
        if (!context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/Login"))
        {
            // Include the path and query string
            var path = $"/Login?ReturnUrl={context.Request.Path}{context.Request.QueryString}";
            // Set the ReturnUrl to a session for later access
            context.Session.SetString("ReturnUrl", context.Request.Path + context.Request.QueryString);
            //Console.WriteLine("Path: " + path);
            context.Response.Redirect(path);
            return;
        }
    }
    await next();
});
```

Then on the /Login page I have a GET and POST

GET:

```
if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("ReturnUrl") != null)
{
    //Console.WriteLine("Return Session: " + HttpContext.Session.GetString("ReturnUrl"));
    ReturnUrl = HttpContext.Session.GetString("ReturnUrl");
}
```

POST:

```
HttpContext.Session.Remove("ReturnUrl"); // Unset the return url if it's present
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
else
    return Page();
```

The issue is when browsing the site when your not logged in the page is broken and the console displays errors when trying to access server resources like css, favicon, js, etc.

[image]

None of the server resources load breaking the point of returnUrl.

How can I make it so ReturnUrl only works on razor pages or ignores server static resources?

Comment: The content URLs should not be authenticated at all... is this asp.net core application? does the application have `wwwroot` folder?

Comment: You should rely on authentication middeware to determine, if a request is authenticated or not, and if so use the Challenge to redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting all requests that are not going to exactly / to /login. This way you cannot load any of the js files without being logged in. You can solve this by excluding the lib folder from your redirect rule, see code below. If you have any other folders that are required to load without logging in you can add it in a similar way.

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    string UserSessionId = context.Session.GetString("_Uid");
    // If the session is not set the user needs to login
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserSessionId))
    {
        // If the current path equals / it's likely the first visit on the site
        // Do not redirect this request
        if (context.Request.Path.Value.Equals("/"))
        {
            await next();
            return;
        }
        // If the path is anything other than /Login require the user to login and return them to the previous URL
        if (!context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/Login") && !context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/lib")
        {
            // Include the path and query string
            var path = $"/Login?ReturnUrl={context.Request.Path}{context.Request.QueryString}";
            // Set the ReturnUrl to a session for later access
            context.Session.SetString("ReturnUrl", context.Request.Path + context.Request.QueryString);
            //Console.WriteLine("Path: " + path);
            context.Response.Redirect(path);
            return;
        }
    }
    await next();
});
```